# Using percents values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll

I have the following code to make an ID visible when scrolled past 100 pixels.

```
window.onscroll = function() {stickyHeader()};

function stickyHeader() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100  document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
        document.getElementById(sticky-header).style.visibility= visible;
    } else {
       document.getElementById(sticky-header).style.visibility= hidden;
    }
}
```

How do I change the 100 pixels in the `scrollTop >100` value to 80% of the page?

Comment: multiple the height of the page by .8?

Comment: You'll probably want `(document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) * 0.8`...

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code because you aren't quoting any strings and you're missing an or logical operator `||`.

the following code should flip the visibility once the user has scrolled 80% of the way down.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {stickyHeader()};

function stickyHeader() {

    var height = (document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight) * 0.8;

    if (document.body.scrollTop > height || document.documentElement.scrollTop > height) {
        document.getElementById('sticky-header').style.visibility= 'visible';
    } else {
       document.getElementById('sticky-header').style.visibility= 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed" id="sticky-header">
sticky-header
</div>
<p style="height:4000px">
</p>
.
```